# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploying Docker with simple SpringBoot Eureka image failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netflix-eureka

I'm new to AWS and Elastic Beanstalk. I'm trying to test a multi-container Docker deployment with a simple Spring Boot Docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/eureka/ just to see something working for now.

I'm uploading a very simple Dockerrun.aws.json file to the Beanstalk console:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "eureka1",
      "image": "springcloud/eureka",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 8761
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The springcloud/eureka Docker image starts by default the server on port 8761, and I'm mapping the host's port 80 to the container's port 8761.

So opening the application's url (something like http://sample-env-1.xxx.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ ), it should display the Eureka server interface... It doesn't. It just says "Unable to connect" standard browser page.

The logs don't appear to indicate an error... Or at least I can't see any obvious error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was putting the "memory" parameter to 128 which probably was not enough. Switching it to "memoryReservation": 128 made it work.

Answer (score 0):

"memory" indicates the Hard Limit and "memoryReservation" indicates Soft Limit. One should always use a soft limit if the developer is not sure about the memory requirement.